# oracle sql query to count based on another query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to know which customer from which country did the most orders. So I have a `sales_table` with the `customer_ids`. But the `country_id` is in the `customer_table`. So I need somehow to count the customers based on the country count... But I have no idea how to do it. I

I know how to count the customers.

```
select count(cust_id)
from sh_sales
```

and how to count the countries

```
select count(country_id)
from sh_customers
```

but i want to count the country based on the `customer_id` which is most often used in the `sh_sales table`

so it should somehow be

```
select count(country_id)
from sh_customers
where sh_sales.customer ????
```

I really need some help here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will count the records in the sh_sales table and group out by each country_id from the customers table

```
SELECT country_id, count(s.cust_ID)
FROM sh_customers c
    INNER JOIN sh_sales s ON c.cust_id = s.cust_id
GROUP BY country_id
```

If, for some reason, you could have a customer record, but no sales then you can use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to return a NULL for countries without any sales

Comment: So now it displays me every country and right next to it the count of customers from this country, correct?